# Jquery iterate through array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create an array and want to iterate through it using `JQuery`. How can I do that? I have created an array but I don't know how to iterate through it.

I have tried the below but in vain;

```
var test = ["First element", "Second", "Last"];

$(test).each(function() { 
  var se = test.val(); 
  alert (se);
});
```

Comment: It's a matter of reading the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method on Arrays returns 2 params: `index` and `value`. So your code should be:

```
$( test ).each(function( index, value ) { 
    alert( value );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var numberArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
jQuery.each(numberArray , function(index, value){
     console.log(index + ':' + value); 
});
//outputs: 1:1 2:2 3:3 4:4 5:5
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to add the arguments to [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). In the case of arrays (because each works on both arrays and objects) the second argument is the array element itself (the first is the index number).

```
var test = ["First element", "Second", "Last"];

$(test).each(function(index, element) { 
  var se = element;
  console.log(se);
});
```

The vanilla JS equivalent:

```
test.forEach(function (el) {
  console.log(el);
});
```

Comment: You should note that the `forEach` is [only supported in IE 9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). But there is a polyfill at the bottom of the page.

Comment: And if you need it there a [polyfill on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it better with normal JS now you'll find both implementations in [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omarqa/bbg17fc9/)

```
var test = ["First element", "Second", "Last"];

//JQuery 
$(test).each(function(index) {
    alert(test[index]);
});

//vanilla JS
test.forEach(function(element) {
    alert(element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use [**jQuery.each( array, callback )**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) with an array:

```
var test = ["First element", "Second", "Last"];
$.each(test, function( i, v ) { 
    alert( v );
});
```